# Confused as to these loops are equal

Tags: python

Confused as to why one for loop works but one doesn't? Aren't they doing the same thing? Like shouldn't x = y?

```
x = 3

for i in range(8):

    if i > x:
        print i, ">", x
        i = x
print x

y = 3

for i in range(8):

    if y < i:
        print y, "<", i
        y = i
print y
```

Comment: Look closer at `i = x` vs `y = i`

Comment: x = i in the first one at a guess, is your issue. Though you might want to bear in mind that the opposite of > is <= ...

Comment: Please, state what you want to achieve in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both are *not* same in first you have assignment (every time 3 to `i`) `i = x`, while in second you assign counter's `i` value to `y` as `y = i`.

> shouldn't x = y?

No, after first loop `x` remains 3 whereas after second loop `y` becomes 7.

Answer (score 1):

No.

In the first loop you are not reassigning the value of `x`. So x is unchanged in the loop.

In the second loop, you are updating `y` every time `y` is less than `i`